# Setting a bit range in an ordinal

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

[Following my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860538/unexpected-c-c-bitwise-shift-operators-outcome), I need to create a value consisting of a solid range of bits set to 1. I used the following function:

```
void MaskAddRange(UINT& mask, UINT first, UINT count)
{
    mask |= ((1 << count) - 1) << first;
}
```

However, as discovered, it didn't work correctly for `count = 32`. The outcome of `1 << count` in such a case *theoretically* is undefined behavior (or result), and *practically* on x86 it's 1, because shift operand is treated modulo 32.

I want to fix this expression to work correctly for this extreme case also. What's the most simple/nice/efficient way to do this?

Handling this specific case via branching (`if`, `?`) is kinda simple, though ugly, and I bet it's inefficient either.

Another way is to promote the shift operand to a greater type (64bit). I mean the following:

```
void MaskAddRange(UINT& mask, UINT first, UINT count)
{
    mask |= (UINT(unsigned __int64(1) << count) - 1) << first;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Hmm. Can you add a simple, short, concise description of the required behaviour of your function? I'd prefer not to have to reverse-engineer the requirements from the code that's in question.

Comment: `void MaskAddRange(UINT& mask, UINT first, UINT count){...}` is a syntax error in C. Maybe you mean C++?

Comment: @wildplasser: yes, I meant C++. I didn't want to tag the question C++, because the question itself is not related to C++

Comment: In C one would probably write something like `mask |= ((1ull << count) - 1) << first;` and put it in a "function-style" macro, because C knows no call-by-reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never assume anything is inefficient unless you can prove it. The if-else may just as well be more efficient on your architecture+OS than the promotion to 64-bit. I don't think there is any other, sane approach than those two you already posted.

I'd go for the if-else because it *documents the intent* of handling the extreme case. Promoting to 64-bit doesn't indicate that intent.

Comment: Thank you very much for theoretical essay about the guidelines for writing efficient software. However in my particular case I can easily prove the branching is less efficient than a single CPU instruction (already did this). I also believe that a *sane* approach should be assuming some facts based on the "educated guess", followed by the mandatory verification.

Comment: P.S. I agree that using explicit `if-else` actually self-documents the intent to handle a particular extreme case, which is somewhat valuable. OTOH speaking more generally I prefer to write something that inherently covers all the extreme cases (if I can). Then it's easier to see the program flow, without the need to mentally consider all the cases. This usually also leads to a better and more universal formulation.

Comment: Can you provide us with the "single CPU instruction" that you refer to? Because your (or Howard's) function will never ever be a single instruction, I can assure of that. But to cut the discussion short let me say this: on a CPU which supports 64-bit integer operations efficiently, your 64-bit promotion code will be the most efficient. And seeing how you use Windows, you're probably running on a CPU that does support 64-bit integer operations efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
mask |= (UINT(-1)<<first) & (UINT(-1)>>(32-first-count))
```

which is more complicated but should work in any case. Efficiency of this expression with respect to other solutions may depend on architecture and compiler.

Comment: Interesting. However it's prone to another extreme case, where `first=0` and `count=0`.