# Left shift and right shift operations using negative numbers on positive integers

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Left shifting with a negative shift count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945703/left-shifting-with-a-negative-shift-count)

On a 16-bit compiler, why does `32<<-3` or `32>>-1` result in 0?
what is the major reason for such a behaviour

Comment: This is undefined behavior, and will vary depending on which c implementation you use.  But the question's also a duplicate.

Comment: "The results are undefined if the right operand of a shift expression is negative" : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From K&R:

**The shift operators << and >> perform left and right shifts of their
left operand by the number of bit positions given by the right operand,
which must be non-negative**

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. It says that the right operand must be non-negative but doesn't say what happens if you do make it negative.

Comment: @quasiverse what happens is exactly what the person who asked the question is experiencing .. confusion

Comment: @quasiverse In doubt, you invoke UB.