# Left shift loop formula

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, formula, bit-shift

I found the following code in a program example:

```
const unsigned int n = /* something */
unsigned int i = 1;
for (unsigned int j = 1; j < n-1; ++j) {
    i <<= 1;
}
```

Is there a direct formula to compute `i` from `n` without a loop ?

Comment: Don't bother, really, any half-decent compiler will optimize the loop away.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think I agree. Why obfuscate the code with a loop like this?

Comment: @jrok - Why tinker with working code that doesn't need to be optimized?  Do you really think that abhishek's snippet is not an obfuscation?  Are you sure it is accurate?

Comment: @HansPassant I wrote the comment before Abhishek edited his answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More accurately:

> assuming unsigned int is 16 bits (minimum as specified by C++ standard)

```
i = ( n < 18 ) ? ( ( n >= 2 ) ? ( 1 << (n-2) ) : 1 ) : 0;
```

Comment: +1 Exactly -- Shift by negative value is undefined at best. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945703/left-shifting-with-a-negative-shift-count

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: well, still incomplete though; if an `unsigned int` as 32 bits, then `1 << 40` will be undefined too; so you need to guard both against underflow and overflow.

Comment: But if `unsigned int` isn't 32 bits, then your magic number will be wrong.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Well I hope now it takes into account the minimum range specification as per C++ standard. However, the original code posted by OP didn't have this check either.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: Indeed; it would be better to omit that check (documenting the precondition on `n`), or use a value calculated from `sizeof i`. Now, your magic number is wrong if `unsigned int` isn't 16 bytes.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I would not say it's wrong; it is restricted, but technically correct, and without any more specification for a valid input range for `n` there is little what can do.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Sorry, "wrong" was a simplification of "not a valid optimisation unless there are restrictions on the inputs that we don't know about". I usually try not to be too pedantic at the weekend; perhaps I should steer clear of SO today.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
i = 1 << (n - 2);
```

or more strict:

```
#include <limits.h> /* for CHAR_BIT */

const unsigned int n = /* something */;
unsigned int i  = 1;

if( (n - 2) > 0 && (n - 2) < (sizeof(i) * CHAR_BIT) ) {
  i = 1 << (n - 2);
}
```