# Bitwise comparisions

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, a = 0xfffffff;
    cin >> n;
    while (n--) {
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        int c = 0;
        for (char ch : s)
            c |= 1 << (ch - 'a');
        a &= c;
    }
    cout << __builtin_popcount(a) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code is to find if a character is present in all the inputted strings at least once.
Can someone explain whats happening in this code.
I am trying to learn bit wise operations in C++ and I am not able to understand whats going on here.

Comment: where did you get this code? you should give credits and if possible ask the author what was his intention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is not to determine if a particular character is present in all strings.

It is to find the number of characters that are present in all strings.

Here's the breakdown of the code.

```
    int n, a = 0xfffffff;
    cin >> n;
```

n is the input parameter from the user which determines the number of strings. Let's say n is 3

```
    while (n--) {
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        int c = 0;
        for (char ch : s)
            c |= 1 << (ch - 'a');
        a &= c;
    }
```

This is the main part of the code..

you get n strings and for each string you store what characters it is composed of, in a bit array

For eg, let's says first string is "stack". you loop through the characters here

```
    for (char ch : s)
        c |= 1 << (ch - 'a');
```

c is initialized to 0 for every string.

In this example "stack", lets see what happens to c

> c = c | 1 << ('s'-'a') => c = c | 1 << 18 (18th bit of c is set to 1)
>
> c = c | 1 << ('t'-'a') => c = c | 1 << 19 (19th bit of c is set to 1)
>
> c = c | 1 << ('a'-'a') => c = c | 1 << 0 (0th bit of c is set to 1)
>
> c = c | 1 << ('c'-'a') => c = c | 1 << 2 (2nd bit of c is set to 1)
>
> c = c | 1 << ('k'-'a') => c = c | 1 << 10 (10th bit of c is set to 1)
>
> > note that 1 << n means that 1 is left shifted by n digits. so 1 << 3 is = 0001 << 3 = binary 1000 = 2^3 = 8 (In case you did not understand shifting)

now c is a integer whose 0,2,10,18,19 bits are set to 1. a is initialized to all 1's before the loop.

> a &= c; this gets rid of all 1's except 0,2,10,18 and 19.

we continue this for all strings. and at the end, a will have 1 bit set in the position which is occupied in all strings..

For eg, if string two is "aaaaa"

> computing c reveals that c has only its 0th bit set.
>
> a &= c; this gets rid of all 1's except 0 (ie.,  it sets 2,10,18 and 19th bits to 0, since they don't occur in "aaaaa")

and string 3 is "zzzzza", at the end, only 0th bit of a will be set

Hence, the number of characters that occurs in all these strings is 1

Answer (score 2):

There's not much going on in here, and breaking it down bit by bit reveals what it does:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  // Initialize a bitmask, here assumed to be 32-bits
  // which is probably "enough" for this case.
  int n, a = 0xfffffff;

  // Read in the number of strings to process
  cin >> n;

  // Assume n > 0
  while (n--) {
    string s;

    // Read in a string
    cin >> s;

    int c = 0;

    // For each character in this string
    for (char ch : s)
       // Turn on a bit on representing the character, where
       // 'a' is bit 0, 'b' is 1, etc.
       c |= 1 << (ch - 'a');

    // Apply this mask to a
    a &= c;
  }

  // Report on which bits are toggled
  cout << __builtin_popcount(a) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This is some seriously sloppy code on the whole. Any non lower case letters could cause undefined behaviour. Most compilers are 64-bit for modern machines so setting only 32 bits might be insufficient.

Note that when I use the word "assume" here I mean *bad things will probably happen*.

Comment: "Toggle a bit" `|=` doesn't *toggle*, it *sets*

Comment: I can change the phrasing, but I mean "toggles it on".

Comment: Strangely, there are only 7 f's in `a` initialization, not 8. Which means the mask only has 28 bits set. I guess the author of the code only needs 28 since there are only 26 letters in the alphabet?

Comment: @KABoissonneault That's a good observation. This whole chunk of code is in dire need of refactoring. I'm not sure why it doesn't start at zero instead of an arbitrary number of 1s.

Comment: Well there are 26 letters, so 28 is enough.

Comment: @coyotte508 ß, þ, æ? Huge assumptions being made here.

Comment: @coyotte508 28 is enough, but isn't it too much? As far as I understand, if all 26 letters are found, it should report that 2 bits weren't unset

Comment: @KABoissonneault Yeah, I think `{` and `|` must be present in the string to flip them all to zero.

Comment: @KABoissonneault no, but if '{' or '|' are present in **all** strings, then the result will be more than expected, that is indeed a behavior error.

Comment: @tadman: If it started at zero, it would always be zero. Also, there's no problem if `a` is 64 bit, although `int` is 32-bit on every 64-bit platform I know about.

Comment: @KABoissonneault: any extra 1's in `a`'s initial value disappear with `a &= c;`.

Comment: @Kundor upper case letters would cause negative shift which is undefined behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945703/left-shifting-with-a-negative-shift-count

Comment: @coyotte508: That's true, although I'm not sure why you're telling me. ;-)

Comment: @Kundor well, because of the "there's no problem", but yea, you were referring to something different, my bad!

Comment: @kundor Ah, you're right, though there's [reason enough for confusion there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models). I still think using `uint32_t` would be a lot better than just `int` and leaving it up to the whims of the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first take a look at

```
int c = 0;
for (char ch : s)
    c |= 1 << (ch - 'a');
```

You represent the characters of your input string bitwise by using the variable **c**:

- If character *a* occurs in the string, bit 0 in variable **c** is set to 1,
- If character *b* occurs in the string, bit 1 in variable **c** is set to 1,
- If character *c* occurs in the string, bit 2 in variable **c** is set to 1,
- and so on.

All other bits in **c** are zero.

After you are finished with one string, the code

```
a &= c;
```

gets executed. This code sets a bit in variable **a** to 1 iff it was 1 before and the corresponding bit in **c** was 1 too. Then the function moves on the reading the next string and does the same again.

At the end of execution, exactly those bits of **a** are set to 1 that were 1 in all the **c**'s in the while block.