# How to make php code "echo 62837 << -16;" return same result between windows and linux?

Tags: php, des

How to make php code "echo 62837 << -16;" return same result between windows and linux?

windows result:-176881664

linux result:-759700962142060544

Comment: I think it's an issue of data format, Windows host could be 32bit and Linux 64bit?

Answer (score 2):

Shifting by a negative number throws an exception in PHP 7+ so it's obviously invalid to do so.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArithmeticError: Bit shift by negative number
```

In C, it invokes undefined behavior, see: [Left shifting with a negative shift count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945703/left-shifting-with-a-negative-shift-count)

**To answer your question:** You can't make code that invokes undefined behavior return consistent results across platforms. That code needs to be modified to not shift by a negative number.

Comment: I got the code from http://www.tero.co.uk/des/code.php.
A DES Source Code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12772293)

Comment: @JonathanArgentiero I believe you've incorrectly flagged this question.

Comment: @JonathanArgentiero I reworded the answer, however if the OP asks how to make *invalid code* work then I consider telling them *the code is invalid* a valid answer. I will not rewrite some (originally not mentioned) DES encryption functions for them.