# Understanding the arithmetic in `(1 << j) - 1`

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

Would appreciate help in explaining the following bit operation. Pardon my lack of understanding of bit arithmetic.

```c
int max = ~0;   
int left = max - ((1 << j) - 1);
```

What will be the result of this operation? Is `(1<<(j-1))` equivalent to `((1 << j) - 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(1 << j) - 1` is a number with `j` *one* bits on the right

```
        j bits
       ┌──────┐
00...0011...111
```

`max` is a number with *all one* bits

```
11...1111...111
```

Each one bit from `max` will become 0 when subtracting from the one bit from `(1 << j) - 1`, and remain 1 otherwise. Hence `max - ((1 << j) - 1)` will produce a value with j zero bits on the right

```
           j...210 ← bit position
    11...1111...11
 -  00...0011...11
──────────────────
    11...1100...00
```

That means the result is the bitwise not of `(1 << j) - 1`, i.e.

```
max - ((1 << j) - 1) == ~((1 << j) - 1)
```

> Is (1<<(j-1)) equivalent to ((1 << j) - 1)?

`1 << (j-1)` shifts 1 `j-1` places to the left and produces 2<sup>j - 1</sup>, so it has `j-1` zeros on the right followed by a one `100...00`. `(1 << j) - 1` gives a number with `j` zeros on the right which is 2<sup>j</sup> - 1, as said above. Can you guess they're similar or not?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below formulas,

- Case : 1

  ```
  (1 << j) - 1) is equal to 2^j-1 [j = 1,2...]
  ```
- Case : 2

  ```
  (1<<(j-1)) is equal to 2^(j-1) [j = 1,2,3...]
  ```

> Is (1<<(j-1)) equivalent to ((1 << j) - 1)?

**No**, Obviously from above formulas.

> What will be the result of this operation?

For this question, **max** will be "**-1**" [bitwise NOT(0) is equivalent to complement of all bit values of 0]

then formula will be

***left* = -(2<sup>j</sup>)**

If **j = -1 or j = 0**, then the above formulas won't work as expected, because ***1<<-1*** is undefined behavior in C. More details found at below links.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4945765/3979414

http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.7.html